# Can trapping one goblin prevent all spawns in a biome?

Tags: terraria

I had an interesting thought while browsing the terraria wikis. It claims that the goblin army [blocks biome spawns.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Army#Notes) Could someone lure a goblin into a hole and trap it to avoid  fighting any enemies in that biome?

If so, will it work in the corruption for farming [The Eater of Worlds](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=terraria%20the%20eater%20of%20worlds&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fterraria.gamepedia.com%2FEater_of_Worlds&ei=v9VTVNzEL4HtoATI4YHYDw&usg=AFQjCNF2sn76SF3EMpPYzFyaK6DC1gtulA) (or any other biome restricted boss) without having to deal with that biome's mobs during the fight?

any evidence (like a screenshot/code) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question simply, **No**.

The Goblin Army Event will finish once it finished spawning all of the goblin waves, and so trapping one will be useless to you because once the event ends, normal mob spawning resumes.

Comment: Some of the effects of the goblin army may stay if even one survives, as I had to scour my map to find the one goblin that kept my npc from respawning.

Comment: Well I guess the real question is can you actually spawn bosses during the Goblin Army Event.

Comment: @Reafexus check my first link, it states that a boss AND an army may spawn on the same night.

Comment: But can they spawn at the same time? Same night and concurrently are not equivalent. The Goblin Army is not an all-night event.

Comment: @Reafexus Yes they can. It is possible.